# sql query not pulling records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason SQL does not pull required info from needed table. Which is odd because I use exactly same code for pulling list of Folders associated with user id from SQL and that works like it should. So a URL query would look something like this ?o=folder&fid=0ec741fa-e708-4314-83c4-c05966a56110, fid is the folder ID and the query below should pull any files assosiated with such folder ID but instead there is nothing being returned, not even an error message/code.

Is there a problem with the syntax? Or what is the cause of the problem?

CORRECTION I USED WRONG CODE AS I HAVE BUNCH OF TABS OPEN IN NOTEPAD++

Here is the actuall code written in SQL PDO

```
require ("sql/pdo.php");

    // Lets get user's folder information
    $query = " SELECT * FROM files WHERE fid = ".$_REQUEST['fid']." "; 

    try 
    { 
        // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute(); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    // Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

?>
<table width="100%"> 
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
        <tr onclick="window.location = 'file.php?fid=<?php echo htmlentities($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."'"> 
            <td style="width:4%;"><img src="ast/images/fs-directory.png" /></td>
            <td style="width:86%;text-align:left;"><?php echo htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td style="width:10%;text-align:center;"><?php echo htmlentities($row['privacy'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
        </tr> 
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</table>
```

Comment: **Think about this** someone does something like this `site.com/?f=drop table fs_files`

Comment: @iight firstly there is no possible way to guess the folder hash, and secondly you need to be logged in not to mention that i do validate where ever the requested folder actually belongs to the user_id and there is also a global token assigned to user during login so there is no way to forge this as its re-assigned every login

Comment: @Cl' just checking!...this code seems to show otherwise.

Comment: try executing the sql statement inside your sql prompt like in the SQL tag in phpmyadmin and see the results

Answer (score 3):

In your query u are using `$_GET['f']`

but in your url u are passing `fid`

code might work when u replace `$_GET['f']` with `$_GET['fid']`

```
<?php

             $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fs_files` WHERE fid = '".$_GET['fid']."'") or die(mysql_error());


             while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

                 if (in_array($row['file_type'], array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) { 

                 $img = "obj.php?id=".base64_encode($row['file_path'])."&mode;thumb";

                 } else {

                 $img = "assets/filesystem/file_extension_".$row['file_type'].".png";

                 }

                 $type = $row['file_type'];



                 $file_name = substr($row['file_name'], 0, 50);
                 $file_path = "view/".$_GET['fid']."/".$row['id']."/".$row['file_name'];

                 echo '<a href="?p=view&f='.$row['id'].'&q='.$file_path.'"><img src="'.$img.'" />'.$file_name.'
                 <span style="float:right;">'.$type.'</span></a>';
             } 
             ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is basically correct, you should use PHPmyadmin or other tools to check the content of the database to see what it's retrieving.

Be careful because putting values inside the SQL query directly from the GET parameters is dangerous, in your case someone (or a n automatic script) may inject an arbitrary SQL code using the 'f' GET parameter. You should escape it removing all characters not strictly used by your case (for example, keep only letters and numbers).

The same applies to the same parameters inside `$file_path`, it could be used to insert an arbitrary image from anywhere in internet, or even a script or an arbitrary HTML code.

You should describe your table schema to understand what's happening here.

Comment: Ok, so now the only thing to do is to inspect the table and try the query inside PHPMyAdmin or another tool to see if data is correct